Duda sobre las iteraciones con el bucle for en Python
No logro entender la diferencia en el funcionamiento del bucle for para estos dos casos:
Primer caso:
nombre = 'Ricardo'
for i in nombre:
    if i == 'R':
        print('r'+nombre[1:])

En este caso el resultado es: 'Ricardo' (no se supone que debería imprimir el nombre 'ricardo' la cantidad de veces como caracteres tiene el nombre 'Ricardo' porque está dentro del bucle for?
Segundo caso:
nombre = 'Ricardo'
for i in nombre:
    if nombre[0] == 'R':
        print('r'+nombre[1:])

En este caso he sustituido la variable iteradora i por nombre[0] (es decir, le estoy diciendo a Python que si el índice 0 en la palabra nombre es igual a 'R' debe imprimir: 'ricardo' por lo que esperaría que el resultado fuera el mismo que el del caso 1 pero no es así, ya que imprime como resultado:
ricardo
ricardo
ricardo
ricardo
ricardo
ricardo
ricardo

Es decir imprime 'ricardo' la cantidad de veces como caracteres tiene la palabra 'ricardo'
Para corregir esto simplemente coloqué un break al final del código como sigue:
nombre = 'Ricardo'
for i in nombre:
    if nombre[0] == 'R':
        print('r'+nombre[1:])
        break

Y asunto arreglado, (imprimo el nombre 'ricardo' y luego detengo la iteración con break eso lo entiendo, pero lo que no entiendo es por qué necesito poner este break en este caso (caso2) y no en el primer caso (caso 1)
Lo mismo se aplica en la iteración de elementos en una lista o vector por ejemplo y siempre he tenido esta duda y quiero entender a la perfección por qué hago lo que hago.
Agradecería mucho me respondieran, sé que es algo muy básico y casi siempre arreglo este tipo de problemas pero sin entender por completo la lógica del funcionamiento de este tipo de bucle.
Muchas gracias de antemano!

En Python el bucle for puede iterar sobre varias estructuras, entre ellas las cadenas, ejemplo:
for c in 'Hola':
    print(c)

El resultado será:
H
o
l
a

Entonces en el primer código que pones, está pasando exactamente lo que acabo de describir.
En la primera iteración i = 'R', el if se cumple y lo que se hace dentro es concatenar 'r' + 'icardo' y por eso imprime: ricardo.
En la siguientes interaciones i = 'i', 'c', 'a', ... etc; por lo que ya no se va a cumplir más la condición del if y por eso solo se imprime 1 vez. A menos que encuentre otra 'R' mayúscula. Puedes probar esto último cambiando (por ejemplo) nombre = RicaRdo.
[*] En programación, las variables deben ser lo más descriptivas posible. En este caso, i no representa un índice, si no el valor directo. Mejor debería nombrarse elem o c (de caracter)... o n si es un elemento numérico, k si es una llave (diccionarios), etc.
nombre = 'Ricardo'
for c in nombre:
    if c == 'R':
        print('r' + nombre[1:])

En el segundo código que pones, nombre[0] siempre será 'R', por lo que no importa los valores que tome i, siempre se va a cumplir la condición, por eso imprime 'ricardo' por cada letra que tenga la cadena.

En otros lenguajes como C/C++ es usual iterar sobre los índices (0, 1, 2...) de las estructuras de datos como las cadenas. En Python también se puede hacer.
El siguiente código es homólogo al primero, pero usando índices. Acá si se usa una variable con nombre i.
nombre = 'Ricardo'
for i in range(len(nombre)):
    if nombre[i] == 'R':
        print('r' + nombre[1:])

La salida es: ricardo
Puedes hacer pruebas de escritorio, ACA

Lo que pasa es que en el primer caso el (if) se realiza sobre el valor que tiene el índice (i) que es 'R' el cual es verdadero una sola vez,  por lo tanto imprime 'ricardo' solo para ese índice . En el segundo caso el (if) se realiza al valor del arreglo ('Ricardo') en su posición (0) el cual será verdadero para cada índice en el arreglo 'Ricardo'. Por lo tanto imprime 'ricardo' por cada índice independientemente del valor que tenga. Saludos
